# Snowflake - CTE joining before filtering? (data type error)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

In snowflake I have the following query

```
With CTE as(
select account_id -- sloppy unvalidated field with text
from mytable
where try_to_numeric(account_id) is not null
)
select *
from
accounts
inner join CTE on accounts.account_id = CTE.account_id
```

--- result -- error -- "my dog is cool" from CTE is not a number!

does the join occur before the try_to_numeric filter? seems like it! Is there a query plan that indicates this for certain?

Comment: Please can you update your question with sample data for both the mytable and accounts tables - that gives you this error? I've tried this and it works as expected, no errors

Comment: You don't want to be at the mercy of the query engine with the subquery approach. I would dump the output of CTE to a temp table with appropriate data type and then filter as usual.

Answer (score 0):

This exact problem is a "known" historical optimization. That you have now learn to know.

The solution is in the CTE cast the select value thus,

```
with cte as (
    select 
        /* sloppy unvalidated  field with text */
        try_to_numeric(account_id) as account_id_safe 
    from mytable
    where account_id_safe is not null
)
select *
from accounts as a
join CTE 
    on a.account_id = cte.account_id_safe
```

This tell the compiler you are only wanting the "altered values" otherwise it see the OG value is used, so uses it prior to filtering, because the "results" should be the same... albeit it is not safe.

If that still explodes you could change the WHERE to a QUALIFY, but I suspect the compiler will treat it all the same at which point, for this toy SQL your could be:

```
select 
    *
from accounts as a
where a.account_id in (select try_to_numeric(account_id) from mytable)
```

or if assuming no duplicates on `mytable`

```
select 
    a.*
from accounts as a
join mytable as mt
    on a.account_id = try_to_numeric(mt.account_id)
```

because `NULL = NULL` is false